# Is there any country in South America that doesn't allow multiple entries within a certain period of time? (Anti Visa Run)

Tags: visas, borders

I'll be traveling in South America for a a while and will more often than not cross a border.
I won't be staying in any country longer than the 90 days I'm allowed to anyway (so no Visa Run necessary for me), but I might be entering a country several times.

I heard that there are some countries that purportedly don't allow (or that at least are planning to not allow) reentering the country within X days to avoid Visa Runs. I don't think that this applies to any country in South America, but I'd like to have this verified.

So, is there any country where I can't reenter within a certain period of time?

Comment: I have a feeling this will be closed as too broad, but can you clarify "right away"? Same day, next day, a week...?

Comment: @mkennedy Too broad because "right away" isn't specific enough? Yeah, I should probably remove these two words. (Actually, I just did so.) But I don't think it really matters if it's the same day, same week. I guess most countries don't have such a limit anyway, and those that do, probably have completely different conditions. So either the answer is "No, there's no country", or "Yes, there's a limit in country X with 10 days and country Y with 30 days and ..."

Comment: Too broad because too many countries! But I'm been wrong before on whether specific questions are on-topic or not.

Comment: @mkennedy Well, I consider a general question very useful. I even searched for it in the first place. As I didn't find any, I was thinking to ask my question in a much broader way and let it deal with any country in the world. Then I decided to narrow it down to SA though, and to ask on meta if a canonical question makes sense, but there's a limit of how many posts I can create. (I guess I can create the meta question any minute.) Just consider the opposite: Over time, we would have about 200 questions asking the same question (10 of which were mine ^^). Anyway.

Comment: Your nationality might also influence the answer.